# React-Widgets DateTimePicker: Prevent keyboard input or copy pasting

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use the [DateTimePicker](http://jquense.github.io/react-widgets/api/DateTimePicker) component from [react-widgets](https://github.com/jquense/react-widgets)

Is it possible to disable keyboard input (and copy pasting) for the DateTimePicker input field and only constrain dropdown selection.

The `disable` API disables everything, including the dropdown selection menu. My intent is to constraint which values the user is allowed to select, and I can only do it from the dropdown menu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
<DateTimePicker
  inputProps={{
    component: props => <input {...props} readOnly />
  }}
/>
```

There's an [active issue](https://jquense.github.io/react-widgets/api/DateTimePicker/) in react-widgets
repo to allow to set `readOnly` for just the input, which would accomplish this task more elegantly.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by handling onChangeRaw that listens for changes on the input and setting the current field value to empty string.

```
<DatePicker
  value={this.state.startDate}
  onChangeRaw={event =>
      this.setState({startDate: ''})}
  onChange={value =>
      this.setState({startDate: value})}
/>
```